# In expect script, output of grep is not saved in expect_out(buffer)

Tags: bash, expect

I have a script that greps a file for a certain value but the response of the grep is not saved in expect_out(buffer).  Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

set prompt "(%|>|#|\\$)"
#set prompt "(%|>|\\$)"

set pidBash [ spawn bash ]
puts "\nStarting script....."

send -- "\n"
expect -re $prompt {}
set output $expect_out(buffer)
send -- "grep '^option' /home/pb791b/udhcpd.conf | grep lease\n"
sleep 4
expect -re $prompt {}

set output $expect_out(buffer)
set outputLines [split $output "\n"]
set len [llength $outputLines]
puts "\nlen: $len\n"
for {set i 0} {$i<[expr $len]} {incr i} {
    set line [lindex $outputLines $i]
    puts "line $i: $line"
}

exec kill $pidBash
puts "\nprocess Bash terminated"

puts "End script."
```

Below is my output:

```
pb791b@pb791b-VirtualBox:~/devtest/ngs/base/Tests/shellScripts$ ./temp2.sh 
spawn bash

Starting script.....

pb791b@pb791b-VirtualBox:~/devtest/ngs/base/Tests/shellScripts$ 
grep '^option' /home/pb791b/udhcpd.conf | grep lease
pb791b@pb791b-VirtualBox:~/devtest/ngs/base/Tests/shellScripts$ grep '^option' /home/pb791b/udhcpd.conf | grep lease
option  lease   864000      # 10 days of seconds
pb791b@pb791b-VirtualBox:~/devtest/ngs/base/Tests/shellScripts$ 
len: 3

line 0:  
line 1: grep '^option' /home/pb791b/udhcpd.conf | grep lease
line 2: pb791b@pb791b-VirtualBox:~/devtest/ngs/base/Tests/shellScripts$

process Bash terminated
End temp.sh script.
pb791b@pb791b-VirtualBox:~/devtest/ngs/base/Tests/shellScripts$
```

When I print expect_out(buffer), it prints the grep command and then the prompt but is missing the output of grep  "option  lease   864000      # 10 days of seconds"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `send -- "\n"` and it should work:

```
set pidBash [ spawn bash ]
puts "\nStarting script....."

#send -- "\n"
expect -re $prompt {}
```

With the `send -- "\n"` you should expect the prompt twice (when you login you see the 1st prompt, then you press `\n` and you'll see the 2nd prompt) before sending the grep command:

```
set pidBash [ spawn bash ]
puts "\nStarting script....."

send -- "\n"
expect -re $prompt {}
expect -re $prompt {}
```

Comment: Bingo.  That worked.  Thank you very much.  It also helped me understand how expect_out buffer works.